# Comment vs Answer - When do you consider which one to use?

Tags: discussion

First, I am new to this site so I want to clarify some stuff.

I stumbled upon a [question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7750/maximum-deflection-of-a-beam-with-both-ends-fixed-and-distributed-load/16811?noredirect=1#comment30335_16811) in Engineering Stack Exchange (ESE).

Now, I tried to answer the question: Note that I cannot verify his **design code** or **his location** so I provided a **generic answer**.

[image: Answer(?) to the question]

I had not given that answer just to gain points, but because I have first hand experience in what he wants to do.

Unbelievably, my answer was taken to be a comment and was transferred into the comment by a moderator.

[image: My answer now becomes a comment]

As I search for the [meaning of answer in the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/answer), I found the following:

> Definition of answer
>
> 1. a: something spoken or written in reply to a question - "His answer surprised us."
>      b : a correct response - "knows the answer"
> 2. a reply to a legal charge or suit: plea; also defense
> 3. something done in response or reaction - "His only answer was to walk out."
> 4. a solution of a problem - "More money is not the answer."
> 5. one that imitates, matches, or corresponds to another - "The show is television's answer to the newsmagazines."

I also checked the site when to use comments and i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Can someone point out what I am missing or doing wrong? I just don't want to "earn" reps but to help also the community since it helped me a lot too. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The first version of your answer, and the one Glen reviewed, began:

> I cannot comment so please let me put this here.

In that light, and given that this is not the first time you've tried to circumvent the restriction on comments from low-reputation users, your suggestion that Glen's solution was "unbelievable" seems aggressively disingenuous.

That phrase is also a common red flag. It communicates two things: first, you do understand this content is more appropriately a comment than an answer; second, you do not understand that privileges like [Comment Everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) are earned by contributing to the site.

What Glen did was effectively allow you to leave a comment before you had earned that privilege. Please don't take this as an invitation to keep leaving comments in answers, as that would be very disrespectful both of the site and of the community members who devote some of their time to cleaning up that sort of misuse; but do try to understand that the action he took as a moderator benefited you directly.

In the future, if you feel it's important that you leave a comment but you haven't earned 50 reputation on the site in question, please earn 50 reputation on the site in question.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the guidance you're seeking is within the site's [help center](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help)

The two articles that are most relevant are:
* [How to answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)
* [Why and how are some answers deleted](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

In your specific example, your answer had been flagged as "not an answer."  After reviewing the question and your answer, I did not believe that the original question had been addressed.  So I agreed with the flag and converted your answer into a comment.

Comment: How did my answer not answer the main question? Can you please point out that to me? In that specific question, he asked where to get the value of a certain variable. Am i supposed to answer with 300 words to validate it as answer? In my perspective, the question is simple, so I answered directly. Will my answer still be considered comment?

Comment: @JemEripol - please re-read the question carefully.  Neither the application nor the location are specified.  The OP is trying to understand how to manipulate the parameters of the associated beam equations to resolve their design issues.  Please read Chris Johns' answer and see how it provides guidance on how to manipulate the design.  Finally, take a look at the dates on the earlier posts.  The OP asked that question about 18 months ago.  Unless you have a stellar answer to provide, it's better to leave old, already answered posts alone.